# Angular how to change number value with leaving its origin value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For example I have number 100. I want that when I write 50 on another input, it would add 50 to 100 and after I change the value 50 to 80, the value would be 180 not 230.

It should always add numbers to its origin not the new value.

Not like this : `this.number=+ 50 = 150 , this.number=+ 80 = 230;`

Like this : `this.number=+ 50 = 150 , this.number=+ 80 = 180;`

Comment: Keep two variables - one is the *base*, the other is what you display, so you have `display = base + 50` or `display = base + 80`.

Comment: I can't keep two values, I have only one. Looking for mutation answer

Comment: @VLAZ that doesn't get updated when the value is changing.

Comment: @Maryannah sorry, but due to my lack of experience with Angular, I can't supply the exact code needed, so I was hoping you take that as pseudo-code. That's how you *usually* solve these sorts of problems - you don't mutate your base value but keep it separate from whatever does the displaying.

Comment: @VLAZ I see, then FYI we can create getters !

Answer (score 2):

Like this ?

```
<input [(ngModel)]="number" type="number">
<input [value]="number + 100" type="number">
```

In "Typescript logic" :

```
get plusHundred() {
  return this.number + 100;
}
```

Comment: Only in typescript logic

Comment: solved it by just adding this : {{calcService.discountValue + calcService.discountAllValue}} , your answer gave me some quite instant insight :D

Comment: @FutureWeb This is not the same thing. Also, if this solved your problem, then accept the answer.

Comment: @Maryannah I don't think it is good practice to call your variable `number`.

Comment: @MauriceNino I'm not the one calling the variables.

Comment: @FutureWeb great, well if it helped you, feel free to upvote it, and feel free to post an answer of your own to explain how you achieved that, then mark it as accepted !

Comment: @MauriceNino it's not really *too* bad. It's just generic - it's better to be more descriptive like, say `amount` or `price` or something. But `number` is serviceable if it really doesn't matter what it is, e.g., `function increment(number) { return number + 1}` is perfectly fine as a generic name that also describes its type. Although it could be shorterby making it `num` or `n` and more generic with something like `a` or `x`.

Comment: @VLAZ I think the issue is more about that `number` is a reserved name. That's like calling a variable `var/const` or `class/function`, it's just best to avoid

Comment: @Maryannah but...[it's not reserved](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reserved-words). And in TypeScript `number` is only relevant *in context* for types but it's not special outside of it. It's like making a variable called `array` - it doesn't refer or interact in any way with the `Array` constructor function.

Comment: @Maryannah sorry, didn't notice it in the question.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes it is not reserved and for a generic descriptive solution it would be fine. In "real" code, it would be considered bad practice though. Also, here in this answer it is confusing, because the variable with the name `number` and the type `number` got mixed in one bit of code.

Comment: @MauriceNino I refer you to [what I already said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213728/angular-how-to-change-number-value-with-leaving-its-origin-value/58213753?noredirect=1#comment102804360_58213753). To reiterate: It's not *too* bad, it's generic. It's good if you can be more specific but OK if you do want generic.

Comment: @VLAZ okay, good to know ! but still I agree it's a bad practice, variables should have descriptive names. Although it's not the point of this question, so if you could stop the notifications and get your own room (on SOF, not a motel, you pervs) ... :D

Comment: @Maryannah I agree with you. And yes I am just writing this comment, so that you get a notification ;D